# Strange double free behavior

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, double-free

Below I have a function `trim()`. Which removes the leading zeros from an array of ints. It returns a pointer, which it receives from `malloc()`. While running a loop of successive calls to `trim()` and `free()`. I noticed that the value returned by `trim()` - which was received by `malloc()`, is identical on every iteration.

It is my understanding that *freeing* the same pointer twice, if it is not `NULL`, will result in a *double free* error. Why is a *double free* error not encountered in this situation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, length;
    int n[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int m[] = { 0, 3, 5 };
    int *num;
    int *trimmed, *trimmed_length;

    trimmed_length = &length;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        num = (i % 2 == 0) ? n : m;

        trimmed = trim(num, 3, trimmed_length);

        if (!trimmed)
        {
            printf("trimmed was null\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < *trimmed_length; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", trimmed[j]);
        }   

        printf("\n");

        free(trimmed); 
    }

    exit(0);
}

int *trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length)
{
    int i, j;
    int *res;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    *res_length = (nlength - i);

    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*res_length));

    if (!res)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;

    while (i < nlength)
    {
        res[j++] = n[i++];
    }

    printf("Returned pointer from trim() %d\n", res);

    return res;
}
```

Output:

```
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
456
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
35
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
456
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
35
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
456
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
35
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
456
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
35
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
456
Returned pointer from trim() 11759632
35
```

Comment: Double free's do not result in errors; they result in undefined behavior, where anything can happen.

Comment: Granted. The question I have now is, why does `trim()` return the same value on identical calls? Case in point, if I need to trim a list of numbers, in order to prevent a memory leak, I would need to `free` the result of `trim()` before subsequent calls. In this case though, subsequent calls appear to be returning the same value, from `malloc()`. Should `malloc()` not return a new value for each subsequent call to `trim()`?

Comment: You alloc, you free. There is no bug in your code - at least not the one you refer to. And why should you not use the same bucket again once you emptied it? Single-use memory?

Comment: `i` is unintialised. (hint: use a for() loop) correction: `i = nlength;` still. (one beyond the size)

Comment: @wildplasser Where does `i = nlength`?

Comment: After the first loop in trim(), it *could* be equal to nlength.

Comment: @wildplasser How could that be if the condition in the `for` loop is `i < nlength`? Short of `nlength == 0`, which I admit is a corner case not accounted for.

Comment: **After failing the loop test**, `i` will be `nlength` (unless the `if (n[i] > 0)` condition caused it to break out of the loop earlier) Maybe you could put a debugging printf() there to verify?

Comment: @wildplasser Agreed. I hadn't accounted for the case of negative numbers or only 0 being passed. The function was solely built for use after a call to `pad()`; also assuming all values are >= 0, but not the case of `int n[] = { 0 };`. My apologizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a double free. Consider:

```
void *p1, *p2;

p1 = malloc(10);
free(p1);
p2 = malloc(10);
```

At this point there's no guarantee that p1 and p2 are the same. There's no guarantee they're different. If they happen to be the same, calling `free(p2)` at this point is *not* a double free. The following would be an actual double free:

```
void *p = malloc(10);
free(p);
free(p);
```

Comment: That is what I originally had thought. This is actually a portion of another questions I had posted: *Malloc returning same value - no double free error*. I believe my code follows the exact same paradigm in that question, yet, a double free error is encountered. I will mark this answer as correct, as it is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no *double free()* in your case.

First, you allocate the memory using `malloc()`, then you `free()` it. After a memory block has been free-d, it can be re-allocated (i.e, the same pointer can be returned) using a next call to `malloc()`. It is perfectly legal (and required) to free that, too.

If we look closely at the `C11` spec, chapter §7.22.3.3, it says (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, **made
>   available for further allocation.** If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument **does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

So,

1. Once freed, a memory space (pointed y a pointer) can be re-allocated.
2. Unless the pointer is *just* previously freed by a call to `free()`, it is perfectly legal to call `free()` on the pointer returned by `malloc()` and family of functions.